# A basic doubt on derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have one question regarding differentiation :

1) Why in the definition of Taylor's series it requires the function to be "continuously" differentiable $m$ times in $[a,b]$?

The book I am following shows that the last term in the series is $$\frac{1}{m!}f^{(m)}(\rho)(b-a)^m$$ where $\rho \in [a,b]$

Then do we need "continuous" ?

Comment: Isn't the function required to be infinitely differentiable even? You need that, because the taylor series of $f$ involves the $n$-th derivative for all $n$.

Comment: Because you have any number of derivatives, and if $f^{(n)}$  differentiable it is continous.

Comment: You probably want continuity of $f^{(m)}$ because of some error estimate involving it under an integral. Continuity is the easiest way to ensure integrability.

Answer (score 1):

The [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function at the point $x=a$ is defined as $$\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a)!.$$  For this to be well defined, we need $f^n(a)$ to exist for all $n \geq 0$.  So, the function needs to be infinitely differentiable at the point $x=a$.

For the limit to satisfy $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a)!=f(x)$$ at any point $x=a$, i.e., $f$ is [analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), we need $f$ to be infinitely differentiable at all points (i.e., $f$ needs to be [smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function)).

Comment: I suppose I should also note that there are [smooth, non-analytic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), so the converse of the last sentence is false.